# How to using loop for with javascript [checkform function]?

Tags: javascript

How to using loop for with javascript [checkform function] ?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form )
{
  if (form.text_0.value == "") {
    alert( "Please enter text" );
    return false ;
  }
return true ;
}
</script>
```

I try to using loop for like this

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form )
{
  var y;
  for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
      if (form.text_'y'.value == "") {
        alert( "Please enter text" );
        return false ;
      }
  }
return true ;
}
</script>
```

But not work , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[]` operator:

```
  if (form["text_" + y].value == "") {
```

Comment: Not work, thank `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form )
{
  var y;
  for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
      if (form["text_" + y].value == "") {
        alert( "Please enter text" );
        return false ;
      }
  }
return true ;
}
</script>`

Comment: @robertwisyert [yes it does - here is a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63phjrrd/)